# Is it possible to rollback to a previous version of the Real Time Database rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have, by mistake (...), overwritten with the Firebase CLI the Rules of a Real Time Database instance that have been written through the Firebase Web Console.

Is there a way to rollback to a previous version of the rules?

(Really stupid mistake... I think I will never do it again...)

Comment: The problem is that the rules I had defined through the console were overwritten when I deployed with the CLI... I use to deploy only the pieces that are updated (e.g. firebase deploy --only hosting or firebase deploy --only functions) but this time I had modified several things and I deployed everything.. forgetting that my database.rules.json file was not in sync with the console. Result: I have lost my work of the previous hours...

Comment: Just one precision for potentiel readers: you can de-activate the deployment of the firebase security rules via the CLI by removing the "database.rules" node in the firebase.json file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Firebase doesn't keep previous versions of your database rules. Once you overwrite them they are lost forever. I'm sorry you had to learn this the hard way.

You can [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. They *may* be able to restore these rules from a backup. No promises, but if this is a production database it may be worth a shot.